# Trying to loop through an CopyOnWriteArrayList and remove items if they're "dead" Java

Tags: java

So for a lab in my CS class, I have to simulate an arena where there are contestants, and I want to loop through an ArrayList in a nested for loop within a while loop to basically go through the list over and over until all contestants are dead. I tried using both an ArrayList and a CopyOnWriteArrayList for iterating through the list, but I can't seem to get the solution just right.

Here is what i need the program to do essentially:

> "In our RPG a set of contestants are to be placed into an arena to battle one
>   another. The area should contain two of each of the classes described below.
>   We should be able to get a description of the arena with everyone in it and
>   the beginning and between each round. Contestants that are dead should be
>   described as such. In each round, all contestants in the arena are given a turn
>   to act, in which they will be able to attack if possible.  When anyone takes
>   damage, it should be announced who took how much, of what kind of damage,
>   from who. After a round, if there is only one contestant left standing, they are
>   to be named the victor. If no one is alive, pick a winner at random from the
>   last to die."

Here is the sample of the code actually using the list.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ArenaSim
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Berserker b1 = new Berserker("Jimmy");
    Warrior w1 = new Warrior("Paco");
    WildMage wm1 = new WildMage("Potato");
    Berserker b2 = new Berserker("Tonto");
    Warrior w2 = new Warrior("Bennett");
    WildMage wm2 = new WildMage("Cletis");

    Contestant winner = null;
    int winnerHP = 0;

    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Contestant> contestants = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Contestant>();
    contestants.add(b1);
    contestants.add(w1);
    contestants.add(wm1);
    contestants.add(b2);
    contestants.add(w2);
    contestants.add(wm2);
    Collections.shuffle(contestants);

    Iterator<Contestant> iter = contestants.iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        Contestant current = iter.next();
        if(current.isDead() == false)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(current.getName() + " prepares to attack!");
            current.attack(contestants);
            System.out.println();

            if (current.getHP() > winnerHP)
            {
                winner = current;
                winnerHP = current.getHP();
            }

            contestants.add(current);

        }
    }

    System.out.println("All contestants have been defeated!");
    System.out.println(winner.getName() + " wins the match!");

}
}
```

The removal of the items is handled within the particular item when they take "damage", so if they have an HP of 0 or less, it removes the item itself from the list passed into it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So what is your question? And what's wrong with the code?

Comment: I suppose he needs to get to an exact answer (like the common counting-circle homework problem), but he sadly neglected to tell us what the expected output is. :(
For what I can see the code runs fine. A few strange choices, but otherwise ok. (Empty lines, simplify `var == false` with `!var`, convert the while into a foreach, ...) EDIT: Oh and a call to a variable (`winner`) that may be null.

Comment: I would even go so far to assume that the task was something like this: `"There are 6 contestants in an arena. All contestants attack one after another the next contestant in line. Dead contestants are skipped. Which contestant wins?"` - Which would be the same issue as counting in a circle, just another wording for it. Obviously one has to add the `hp` and `dmg` of the contestants to get to the expected output.

Comment: I added the prompt of what the program needs to do onto the post, since it wasn't clear at first

Comment: The problem I get is that sometimes it has a nullpointer exception at the very very end, where it's trying to simply call the winner variable. I suppose thats what @showp1984 was saying, but I wouldn't know how to fix it.

Comment: Also, the code only runs once through the whole thing, and not all of the contestants die by the end of it. I want it to run until all of the contestants are dead, or there is one left, whichever one works easiest.

Comment: Remove dead contestants from the list and loop through the list until only one contestant remains. He is automagically the winner. This will also fix the npe at the end, if you move the winner variable behind the loop and initialize it with the only contestant remaining.